# How I do initial JavaScript Ajax initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm pulling information with ajax. I want it my document.ready function(ajax) starting first because knockout file starting first and my "var initialData" value going null. How my Ajax start first ?

[Here is my F12 Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BHFS.png)

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var initialData;
        function functionViewModel() {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "KnockoutGrid2.aspx/GonderUrunler",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            console.log(msg.d);
                            initialData = msg.d;
                        }
                    });
                });
            var fn = {
                friends: ko.observableArray(initialData)
            };
            fn.removeUser = function (item) {
                fn.friends.remove(item);
            };
            return fn;
        };
        ko.applyBindings(functionViewModel());
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**
The answer of @user3297291 is better than mine, because is Knockout who handles all the state of this form.  Please,  **don't do the `applybindings` in the answer of the ajax request**.

The user need to know that the data isn't loaded yet, and this can be handled with knockout.

**Original answer**

Perhaps if you move the initialization of Knockout inside the `success` function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "KnockoutGrid2.aspx/GonderUrunler",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg.d);
                    initialData = msg.d;

                    // All initialization inside the 'success' function
                    function functionViewModel(initialData) {
                        var fn = {
                            friends: ko.observableArray(initialData)
                        };
                        fn.removeUser = function (item) {
                            fn.friends.remove(item);
                        };
                        return fn;
                    };

                    ko.applyBindings(functionViewModel(initialData));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

You could show a div with the message:  "loading data...".

And when `success` run, hide this div.

**Update 1**
After your comment, I don't know why you need the `return fn`.  I propose this solution:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Updating 'functionViewModel()' to add 'self'.
        // Move functionViewModel()' outside ajax response
        function functionViewModel(initialData) {
            var self = this;

            self.friends = ko.observableArray(initialData);

            self.removeUser = function (item) {
                self.friends.remove(item);
            };
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "KnockoutGrid2.aspx/GonderUrunler",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg.d);
                    initialData = msg.d;

                    // All initialization inside the 'success' function

                    ko.applyBindings(functionViewModel(initialData));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here I'm using `self` ( see [Managing ‘this’](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) ) and don't return `fn`, because Knockout handles its state.

Comment: All data see true but this time give this error. U can see here: http://www.imgim.com/844incib776110.png And ı think u forget the write var initialData under the console.log().

Comment: Yep this code is true. But now ı need convert to array to initialData because msg.d coming string and ı need convert this :) Update: I found my answer ı do like this and code work " var initialData = JSON.parse( msg.d); " All is fine now thx again :))

Comment: Oh, one thing, the `functionViewModel()` could be moved outside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Even though this *works*, it's not how it should be done. Applying bindings only after all your data is loaded defeats one of the main purposes of observable/data-bound properties.

Comment: @user3297291 Thank you, you are right, Knockout can handle all the state, including the waiting till the data can be showed from the Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Use `async:false` in your code

```
                   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "KnockoutGrid2.aspx/GonderUrunler",
                        data: "{}",
                        async : false,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            console.log(msg.d);
                            initialData = msg.d;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Still same...But give this warning: " jquery-3.1.1.js:9425 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.or "

Comment: so initialdata is still blank?

Comment: Yep still blank. U can see here: http://www.imgim.com/1024incij4042449.png

Comment: Why dont you put your (var fn=) part inside success function

Comment: This time (var Fn) does not appear. I think knockoutJs doing someting but ı dont know the answer... And var Fn going blank to.  And ı got 2 error.  Image here: http://www.imgim.com/6873incib9929685.png

Comment: I think your initialData is not an array

Comment: If ajax work initialData going to array because my code sending json array list to initialData. Look last image my json data  under the warning.  Data coming true and perfectly but ajax not starting first because of this (var fn) see initialData null.

Comment: Setting async to false is *not* the solution to this problem. Even if you can get it to work. The whole point of using knockout is that it's easy to work with dynamic data sets without worrying about when and how to update your UI...

Answer (score 1):

You **do not** want to wait with `applyBindings` until your ajax response is handled... Your document will look ugly if you let knockout wait with applying bindings and your users will have nothing to look at.

What you *should* do:

- Apply bindings as soon as `$(document).ready` triggers
- Make sure your viewmodels use `observable` properties that allow you to easily inject data later on
- Make sure you define some sort of loading state to show your users the data is being downloaded

I.e.:

```js
function functionViewModel() {
  var friends = ko.observableArray([]);
  var loading = ko.observable(true);
  var removeUser = function(user) {
    friends.remove(user);
  }
  
  // Get the data and write it to an observable property once done
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "KnockoutGrid2.aspx/GonderUrunler",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      friends(JSON.parse(msg.d));
      loading(false);
    }
  });
    
  return {
    friends: friends,
    loading: loading,
    removeUser: removeUser
  };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(functionViewModel());
});
```